# "Deveni el" or "veni el"?

Tags: word-choice

I've seen *deveni* used in places where it seems *veni* would work as well.

I originally learned *Mi venas el Usono*.

If I say *Mi devenas el Usono*, how does the meaning change? "I originally come from the U.S."?

Could I say, for example, "Mi venas el Georgio, sed devenas el Luziano"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's about the same as the difference between "come from" and "originate from." Often the meaning doesn't change much, but sometimes it can.

PIV (vortaro.net) sums it up pretty well.

1. ***veni de ia origino, fonto***: el sama tero devenas, saman sukon
   entenas<sup>Z</sup>; ilia reganto devenas el ilia propra mezo<sup>X</sup>; la itala lingvo
   devenas de latino; antaŭe la lumgaso devenis nur de la karbo.
2. ***Esti
   ido de:*** la hebreoj estas Izraelidoj, ĉar ili devenas de Izraelo<sup>Z</sup>; mi
   devenas de Tantalo<sup>Z</sup>; ilia devenantaro estas antaŭ iliaj okuloj<sup>X</sup>.
3. ***Rezulti de:*** la patologia graseco devenas de abunda manĝo k de manko
   de movado<sup>B</sup>.

I didn't find many examples of *veni* and *deveni* used in the same context.

- Amanda ne devenis de la vilaĝo. Ŝi venis de iu fora, arbara farmeto

Her origin was not in the village, but rather she changed her location from a distant farm to her current location in the village.

- La du kontraktantoj rapide venis al konsento. La monon, devenantan de la vendo de lia bieno, la bankiero utiligis por aĉeti alian kampodomon

The two people parties quickly **came** to an agreement. The money **derived** from the sale of the estate was used by the banker to buy another country house.